# a condition given by step functions implies the condition holds for L^q space

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $1\leq p<\infty$, $1/p+1/q=1$. Let $f$ be a measurable function on $[0,1]$ such that for all step functions $g$ on $[0,1]$,
$$
|\int_0^1 fg d\mu|\leq ||g||_q.
$$

Prove $||f||_p\leq 1$.

How to prove? Thanks.

I have tried but failed: Let $F_f: L^q[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, $F_f(g)=\int_0^1 fg $. If for all $g\in L^q[0,1]$, $$
|\int_0^1 fg d\mu|\leq ||g||_q,
$$
then $$||f||_p=||F_f||=\sup_{||g||_q\neq 0}\frac{|F_f(g)|}{||g||_q}\leq 1.$$
Hence we need to prove for all $g\in L^q[0,1]$, $$
|\int_0^1 fg d\mu|\leq ||g||_q.
$$
Let $\{\phi_n\}$ be a sequence of step functions such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}||\phi_n-g||_q=0$. I want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}|\int_0^1 f\phi_n d\mu|=\int_0^1 fg d\mu$.
By holder inequality, 
$$
\int_0^1 f(\phi_n-g) d\mu\leq ||f||_p||\phi_n-g||_q\to ||f||_p\cdot 0.
$$
But $f$ is not assumed to be in $L^p[0,1]$... what should I do? Thanks.

Comment: Extend by density to a bounded linear operator on $L^q$ and use duality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is good. To show $f\in L^p$, it suffices to show that the functional on $L^q$ defined by $F_f(g) := \int fg$ is continuous and linear. Linearity is clear, to show continuity, first let us look at the inequality for step function $g$
$$\left| \int fg\right| \leq ||g||_q$$
observe that this implies 
$$\left| \int f|g|\right| \leq ||g||_q$$
and further more by spiting $f$ into non-negative and negative parts, we have $$\left| \int |f||g|\right| \leq 2||g||_q $$
Now for any $g\in L^q$, let $\phi_n$ be a sequence of step functions such that $\phi_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^q$ and pointwise a.e., by Fatou's lemma, we can change the limit in the following way
$$\left| \int fg \right| \leq \int|fg| = \int \lim_n |f\phi_n| \leq \liminf_n \int|f\phi_n| \leq \liminf_n 2||\phi_n||_q \leq 2||g||_q$$
which means that the functional $F_f$ is continuous.

Comment: by spiting $f$ into non-negative and negative parts, we have $$\left| \int |f||g|\right| \leq 2||g||_q $$. How to obtain this step?

Comment: @RenShiquan $$\left|\int (f^+ - f^-)|g|\right| = \left|\int f^+ |g| - \int f^- |g|\right| \leq \left|\int f^+ |g|\right| + \left|\int f^-|g|\right| \leq 2||g||_q $$  $$ 2||g||_q \geq \left|\int f^+ |g|\right| + \left|\int f^-|g|\right| = \int f^+ |g| + \int f^-|g| =  \int (f^+ +  f^- )|g| = \int |f||g|$$